# React Router Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I was attempting to add a Navbar to a Webb app and as soon as I put `<Navbar/>` into App.js I get the error below. I've read that the error could be related to the `to` props of `<Link/>` but I can't find any issues there and I'm having trouble making sense of this error. I appreciate all ideas and thank you for your time!

```
> components.tsx:197 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
    at Router (components.tsx:197:1)
```

> react-dom.development.js:18687   The above error occurred in the
>  component:  at Router
> (http://localhost:3003/static/js/bundle.js:62004:15)  at App
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
> handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to
> learn

Navbar:

```
export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className="nav">
      <Link to="/" className="site-title">
        
      </Link>
      <ul>
        <CustomLink to="/reflect">Reflect</CustomLink>
        <CustomLink to="/edi">Edi</CustomLink>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
  function CustomLink({ to, children, ...props }) {
  const resolvedPath = useResolvedPath(to)
  const isActive = useMatch({ path: resolvedPath.pathname, end: true })
  return (
    <li className={isActive ? "active" : ""}>
      <Link to={to} {...props}>
        {children}
      </Link>
    </li>
  )
}
```

App.js:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/reflect" element={<Reflect />} />
        <Route path="/edi" element={<Edi />} />
        <Route path="/storyboard" element={<StoryBoard />} />
        <Route path="/texteditor" element={<TextEditor />} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<errorPage />} />
        </Routes>    
      </Router>
       </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Issue is with `<CustomLink to="/Edi">Edi</CustomLink>` the path. it should be `<CustomLink to="/edi">Edi</CustomLink>`

Comment: Thank you for your help but I made that change and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you make sure that all over your code every `Link` has its `to` prop?

Comment: Yes. The only Link elements in my code are shown above in the NavBar Component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `<Router>`. That requires you instantiate and pass in your own `history` `<Router history={history}>`. Use `BrowserRouter` instead.